# attribute directive on title tag in IE8 does not run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-directive

See below the super-simple directive that's attached to the `<title>` tag. In modern browsers this activates and changes the title to "Title C" but in IE8 the link function is never called and the title remains "Title B".

Are directive attributes supported on the `<title>` tag in Angular in a cross-browser way? I have other workarounds for updating the title value, but I'm looking for something definitive on whether Angular supports this, or why not.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title update-title>Title A</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  body content
  <script>
    window.document.title = "title B";

    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .directive('updateTitle', ['$window', function($window) {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {  },
          link: function(scope, element) {
            $window.document.title = "title C";
          }
        };
    }]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is an odd issue. I can't come up with a logical reason why that directive isn't firing.

However, based on the way your directive is written, the attribute does not need to be on the `title` tag. The following works in IE8:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="myApp">
<head update-title>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  body content
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.document.title = "title B";

    angular.module('myApp', [])
      .directive('updateTitle', ['$window', function($window) {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {  },
          link: function(scope, element) {
            $window.document.title = "title C";
          }
        };
    }]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm no AngularJS guru, but, it doesn't look like that is the proper use case of a directive. According to the docs:

> At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an
>   attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's
>   HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM
>   element or even transform the DOM element and its children.

Since there can only be one title tag on a document, and the title is being set without the DOM element (i.e. `window.document.title`) then it would probably be best done without a directive. Perhaps through a controller? I'd recommend some Google searching to find the common way to handle page titles in Angular.